# Marking a reference as developmentOnly in cproj file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget, resharper

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32024227/6761907) post:

> You reference nuget Jetbrains.Annotations, and DO NOT define
>   JETBRAINS_ANNOTATIONS: Such annotations are useful only for developers
>   working with source code, they are not compiled in your binary
>   (Conditional statement is used) and they are not visible when
>   referencing your dll. You can even add developmentOnly="true"
>   attribute to Jetbrains.Annotations in packages.config, so by default
>   it would not be treated as dependency.

In my cproj file I have:

```
<Reference Include="JetBrains.Annotations, Version=10.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1010a0d8d6380325, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\Build Files\packages\JetBrains.Annotations.10.2.1\lib\net\JetBrains.Annotations.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Can I entirely get rid of this reference and rely on the packages.config entry:

```
  <package id="JetBrains.Annotations" version="10.2.1" targetFramework="net45" developmentOnly="true" />
```

**What is the purpose of including a reference in both the packages.config AND the cproj file, assuming that the cproj file already has a reference to packages.config?**

Comment: that's a nuget responsibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference in the csproj file is used to indicate the hint path of .dll file. You need to specified the path when you calls the Class and Attributes from Jetbrains.Annotations library.

And the package.config file is managed by the NuGet infrastructure. It's used to track and restore the installed packages with their respective versions. 
[See here](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/package-restore) for some details about packages.config.

So they have different usage, you could not entirely get rid of this reference and only rely on the packages.config entry.